# how i can make a Resource Controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

when I want create a Resource Controllers by this command : " php artisan make:controller sectionController3 "
I get a Basic Controllers
I don't add --plain
but he gives me Basic Controllers

sorry ^^

Comment: The laravel documentation refers to resource & restful controllers as being the same thing https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers. I don't really understand your question...

Comment: They are the same https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Did you try `php artisan make:controller sectionController3 --resource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new controller from the command line laravel automatically insert a new resource controller like this:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class sectionController3 extends Controller

{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
      public function index()
      {
           //
      }

      /**
       * Show the form for creating a new resource.
       *
       * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
       */
       public function create()
       {
           //
       }

       /**
        * Store a newly created resource in storage.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function store(Request $request)
       {
           //
       }

       /**
        * Display the specified resource.
        *
        * @param  int  $id
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function show($id)
       {
           //
       }

       /**
        * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
        *
        * @param  int  $id
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function edit($id)
       {
           //
       }

       /**
        * Update the specified resource in storage.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  int  $id
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function update(Request $request, $id)
       {
           //
       }

       /**
        * Remove the specified resource from storage.
        *
        * @param  int  $id
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function destroy($id)
       {
           //
       }
}
```

After this you can create a new route for this controller:

```
resource('section-controller-3', 'sectionController3');
```

and this would handle all the RESTful actions about your sectionController3

Have a look to [Laravel Docs HTTP Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers) to get familiar with how Controllers and Routes work in Laravel.

Hope this helps!